# OpenAL alSourcePlay() in a detached thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, openal

I am trying to play music using C++11 threads. After initializing OpenAL, I have the following code within my `Music::Play()` method:

```
alSourcePlay(source);

ALint source_state;
alGetSourcei(source, AL_SOURCE_STATE, &source_state);

while (source_state == AL_PLAYING) {
  alGetSourcei(source, AL_SOURCE_STATE, &source_state);
  alGetSourcef(source, AL_SEC_OFFSET, &song_time);
}
```

Since this while loop is blocking, I have to run it in a separate thread from my main program logic. I tried adding the following to `main()`:

```
Music music;
std::thread tmusic(&Music::Play, &music);
```

...and it all worked fine. I then decided to move this functionality to a method in my main program class:

```
Program::PlayMusic() {
  Music music;
  std::thread tmusic(&Music::Play, &music);
}
```

I figured that this was not working because the thread object was immediately going out of scope after `Program::PlayMusic()` ended, and the thread was destroyed. I tried detaching the thread from the thread object using `tmusic.detach()`, and that seemed to work okay, but the music only plays some of the time. It seems to be related to the size of the track. My original song was a ~350MB WAV file that I was loading using:

```
buffer = alutCreateBufferFromFile("music.wav");
```

trimming the file down to ~4MB seems to help, but still it only plays some of the time. Any help would be greatly appreciated!